# How to manage different developer management in android studio for product flavors?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two flavor f1 and f2 of a project with two developer D1,D2 and i want that D1 should have access of f1 only and D2 have access of f2 only so how can i achieve this type of functionality.

Comment: What is difference between two flavours? Currently you can not do it with gradle and it should be done on source level and git access. Unless you can solve it with environment variables or gradle parameters

Comment: I have many projects which have some common modules for example Login, Feedback, splash and other for which i have implemented flavors but now i have problem that if developer D1 want to work on flavor f1 then he/she has to clone other flavor also but we want that only Main source set directory should share with all developers.so please suggest some required solution.

Comment: what do you mean by "cloning flavour"?

Comment: I have already setup project on SVN and project has number of flavor and now task is we want to restrict access of flavors to developers and want to give access to a specific developer for specific flavor.